# processing through a dictionary of lists in a Django template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I have a dictionary which looks like this:  list = {item : [thing, thing, thing, thing], item : [thing, thing]}

I am currently trying to display all items and things like so:

```
Item

    thing
    thing
    thing

Item

    thing
    thing
```

I tried

```
{% for item, things in list %}
    -{{Item}}
    {% for thing in things %}
        {{thing}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But my output looks kinda like

```
-

-

-

-

-
```

I have previously tried

```
{% for item in list %}
    -{{item}}
    {% for thing in list[item] %}
        {{thing}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `list.items` to specify that you want to iterate over the (key, value) tuples and not over the keys (like you would do in Python code anyways).

Also you'll have to include some line breaks if you want your output to be somehow more readable.

Something like this should work:

```
{% for item_name, things in list.items %}
    -{{item_name}}<br />
    {% for thing in things %}
        {{thing}}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks!  One question.  item has a field which is a MTM to the model x.  Model x has a property name.  Any reason why `{{ item.x.name }}` doesn't show up?

Comment: `{{ item.x.name }}` means you access the field `x` on the `item`. If field `x` is m2m to a model, but it's actually a `ManyRelatedManager` and does not represent the related model instance (it wouldn't make sense anywhere because you can have multiple associated objects).

Comment: Ah! that would definitely make sense, I didn't think about that.